# HSDPA USB modems and Vista 64-bit

Tags: modem

Does anyone have any experience whether those really handy HSDPA/EDGE/GSM modems available in Europe from makers such as Huawei or iCon are compatible with Vista 64-bit? These products are sold in conjunction with the "mobile internet" or "internet everywhere" packages here, to be used with a notebook or netbook.

None of the Swiss telecom providers seems to be able to provide a conclusive answer whether their stuff works with Vista 64, and all insist on a 24-month contract - no trial period, nothing :-(

Any one using a Huawei e160 or iCON 451 from Orange or Vodafone or some other company on a Vista64 system? (e.g. see [Orange's offering](http://www1.orange.ch/residential_internet_internet-everywhere.html) in Switzerland)

Marc

UPDATE:
The Huawei e172 works fine on Vista 64-bit and Windows 7 RC (64-bit) - thanks for all the responses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Huawei model that is currently being deployed by BT mobile works fine under windows Vista x64.

Comment: OK; thanks for your feedback! You don't happen to have a model number or something? The BT website doesn't really reveal much.....

Comment: As Per Karolis Below, this model also works, I don't have one on hand at present as they are all with people (on Vista x64!) on site with clients. as soon as I get one back I'll post models

Answer (score 1):

I have a Huawey e220 which works fine on Vista 64 and Mac OSX after upgrading firmware and replacing operator given client program with Mobile Partner (for win, has bugs, but so far seems stable).

Though I'm planning on permanently connecting it to my Asus WL-500W (using linux firmware) to remove the dependency of client software on my workstation (mostly use it at home anyway).

This might be of some help: http://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=2055115833

Answer (score 1):

I have a UK Vodafone K3520 which is flagged as HUAWEI FCC QISK3520 which works fine under Windows Server 2008 x64.  Windows 7 x64 is possible but requires a bit more mucking about due to unsigned drivers on that OS.

Under Server 2008 x64 it just installs and works, I'd expect Vista x64 to be the same

Answer (score 1):

marc_s - I'm interested to see that you've got the E172 running with Vista / Win 7 x64.  I just went with Win 7 x64 and the machine dies as soon as it tries to install the driver for the E172.  Can I ask how you managed it?

Cheers
Simon

Comment: Hmm...odd - no idea. I had trouble on my company laptop (Vista64) after the install which went fine - everytime I started the connection manager, it said something like "disconnected" and basically rebooted itself. Never got it working. But in Win7-64 on my home laptop, I just plugged it in, manually installed the 64-bit drivers, and off it went.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  Can I ask where you got the 64bit drivers from?  I suspect the ones on the stick will just be x86 and the Huawei site isn't much help :-/

Comment: In my case, the drivers were on the disk provided by the service provider (Swisscom in my case). They just didn't install automatically - you had to find them and then launch the "setup64.exe" (or whatever it was called)